# how to expand toggle/hyperlink while data scraping in UiPath?

Tags: automation, uipath

[Reference](https://forum.uipath.com/t/how-to-expand-a-url-while-data-scraping-in-uipath/10321?u=kp144)

here i am taking a website for reference and here 202 records are found with this URL, in the second search result there is a toggle/Link written as “1 more location” i want to scrap the data which is contains by the URL.
any help will be appreciate…

Comment: What have you been trying so far? Where do your efforts fall short?

Comment: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/fd56938905e4e7149713d32783230b4f20170824100458/2e2580 please see my work here

Answer (score 0):

After having looked the page over, it seems like the HTML isn't generated when clicking the fold-button. It is merely hidden/unhidden. So I guess you should be able to extract the data, as you have extracted the other data. Just make sure to unfold multiple addresses before you do the scraping.

Btw, your Get Row Item activity does nothing, since you never store the output anywhere :)

Comment: Thanks Nicolai for the response, right now i am storing the whole data into csv file and its working fine. i have expand the data and apply the data scraping but it doesn't work. i have idea but unable to implement if you could help me to do this. there is a div where a CSS is applying to hide that filed. style = "display: none" can we send it through uipath like style = "display: block" so it will be by default expand and we can scrap the data.

Comment: I don't think we can alter the CSS/Style directly. You might have to do one or more scrapings and the do some other actions do stitch the results together - possibly based on the name of the Doctor.

Comment: exact what i was thinking, but how do i scrap again if one scraping process is already running. can you please help me to write the scraping process. i just want the data scraping. thanks @Nicolai

Comment: I would do the scraping AFTER the first scraping. Yes, it will take longer. But it's a robot doing the work, not you. So who cares? ;)

Comment: Hi Nicolai did you find anything. the time is really horrible ;)

Comment: Sorry for any misunderstandings. But I'm not actually trying to make this for you. I'm simply giving you my advice on what you should try :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152766/discussion-between-kuldeep-choudhary-and-nicolai-kruger).